# Radius of a circle containing circles.

Tags: circles

If, inside a big circle, exactly $n (n ≥ 3)$ small circles, each of radius $r$, can be drawn in such a way that each small circle touches the big circle and also touches both its adjacent circles (as shown in the picture), then the radius of the big circle is?
[image]

My approach: 
Let the circumference of the circle formed by joining the centres of the small circles be $2\pi R$.

Circumference of the circle formed by joining the centres of the small circles=$2rn$

Equating, $2rn=2\pi R$
          $=>R=\frac {rn}{\pi}$

Now, the radius of the bigger circle is $r$ more than the $R$ found out previously. Therefore,

Radius of bigger circle$=r+\frac{nr}{\pi}$ = $r(1+\frac{n}{\pi})$

The answer given in my book is, $r(1+cosec\frac{\pi}{n})$
Where exactly am I going wrong?

Edit: I think writing the circumference as $2 rn$ is incorrect because the circumference is actually curved and I'm not sure that I can just keep adding the diameter n times to get the circumference. How should I apply trigonometry here?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is in the claim "Circumference of the circle formed by joining the centres of the small circles =$2rn$". It is true that the *line segment* joining the centers of two touching circles of radius $r$ is $2r$. However, what you really want to calculate is the length of *a circular arc* joining those two centers, which will be slightly longer (and trigonometry will help you calculate how much longer).

Comment: How exactly should I apply trigonometry? I can just think of $l=r \theta$. Would that help?